# postgreSQL declare var inside if statement inside select statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have a mySQL statement that I need to convert to postgreSQL but when I run the following SQL in postgreSQL I get ERROR: syntax error at or near ":="

From what I've found := seems to be the way to declare a var in postgreSQL.

```
SELECT  memberid, conseq, displayname, foldername, apiloginid, countryid, members.email
            FROM    (   SELECT  MemberID,
                                Position,
                                CreateDat,
                                @r:=IF(@m = MemberID, @r + 1, 1) AS conseq,
                                @m:= MemberID
                        FROM    memberevents,
                                (SELECT @r:= 0) r,
                                (SELECT @m:= 0) m
                        where position=1        
                        group by eventid        
                        ORDER BY CreateDat DESC
                    ) t, members
            where members.id=t.memberid     
            ORDER BY Conseq DESC
            LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: For what it is worth, := assigns to a value in Postgres not declares it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for such a hack, just use a window function:

```
SELECT  memberid, conseq, displayname, foldername, apiloginid, countryid, members.email
FROM (   
  SELECT  MemberID,
          Position,
          CreateDat,
          row_number() over (partition by memberID order by createDat) as AS conseq
  FROM  memberevents
  where position=1        
  group by eventid        
) t
  JOIN members ON members.id=t.memberid     
ORDER BY Conseq DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

I'm not sure about the `group by` inside the derived table though as I don't know how MySQL actually uses the variable assignment inside a derived table.